# systemd: myservice.service vs myservice.target

Tags: systemd

In a systemd service definition file, what is the difference between

```
[Unit]
Description=My service...
After=zookeeper.service
```

and

```
[Unit]
Description=My service...
After=zookeeper.target
```

zookeeper is another service defined in another service file, but what is the significance of the extension `.service` vs `.target`. Is there a difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. See `man systemd.service` and `man systemd.target` for the documentation for each type of `systemd` unit.

On your systemd, you can find the files and review what `systemd` directives they contain, assuming both exist:

```
 locate zookeeper.service
 locate zookeeper.target
```

Answer (score 4):

**A service**:

> A unit configuration file whose name ends in .service encodes
>   information about a process controlled and supervised by systemd.

**A target**:

> A unit configuration file whose name ends in ".target" encodes
>   information about a target unit of systemd, which is used for grouping
>   units and as well-known synchronization points during start-up.

These both refer to `unit configuration files`, which are:

> A unit configuration file encodes information about a service, a
>   socket, a device, a mount point, an automount point, a swap file or
>   partition, a start-up target, a watched file system path, a timer
>   controlled and supervised by systemd(1), a resource management slice
>   or a group of externally created processes.

Reference: man pages for `systemd.service`, `systemd.target`, and `systemd.unit`, respectively.

Also, with respect to the configuration files themselves; services need:

> Service files must include a "[Service]" section, which carries
>   information about the service and the process it supervises.

No such requirement exists for `target` configuration files. In fact, targets have no options specific to targets; items are configured in generic `[Unit]` and `[Install]` sections.